# Set of partial limit

Tags: real-analysis

I'm preparing for exams and need to solve this problem.
Let C - closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Prove the existence of a sequence in C that the set of partial limit coincides with the whole set C.
Thanks.

Comment: In order to attract good answers, it is a good idea to show what you have done so far. The answers you get are more likely to be at an appropriate level if you show what you know about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $n-$dimensional nets $\frac{1}{m}\mathbb{Z}^n$ of side $\frac{1}{m}$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let for a fixed $m$
$$\mathbb{R}^n=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}Q_{k}^{m},$$
where $Q_{k}^{m}$ is the cube of side $\frac{1}{m}.$

Now starting from $m=1$, choose an elements $x_k^1$ from such $Q_{k}^{1}\cap C$, $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ that
$$Q_{k}^{1}\cap C\neq\emptyset.$$
For $m=2,$ choose an elements $x_k^2$ from such $Q_{k}^{2}\cap C\,\cap \{x_k^1\}_k$, $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ that
$$Q_{k}^{2}\cap C\,\cap \{x_k^1\}_k\neq\emptyset.$$

For $m=3,$ choose an elements $x_k^3$ from such $Q_{k}^{3}\cap C\,\cap \{x_k^1\}_k \,\cap \{x_k^2\}_k$, $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ that
$$Q_{k}^{3}\cap C\,\cap \{x_k^1\}_k \,\cap \{x_k^2\}_k\neq\emptyset,$$

Finally you'll get the sequance $S=\{x_k^m\}_{k,m=1}^{\infty}$ for which  $S'=C.$